# Installing ScoutMaps SDKTools via CocoaPods with use_frameworks

Tags: ios, cocoapods, skmaps

I have a Swift app that is using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON in addition to the two ScoutMaps pods.

Currently I have Alamofire and SwiftyJSON included manually and ScoutMaps installed via Cocoapods, but I'd like to switch to include them via Cocoapods as well. To do this I will need to enable the use_frameworks! flag in the podfile. However, this causes

My new podfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK'
pod 'ScoutMaps-iOS-SDKTools'
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
```

However, when I try to build the app I receive the following error

```
SKTDownloadObjectHelper.m:8:9: 'AFNetworking.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
```

Editing that file to use either `"AFNetworking.h"` or `<AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>` then causes a cascade of Linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestSerializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTDownloadObjectHelper.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFNetworkReachabilityManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTDownloadManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKAdvisorSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+Factories.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKAnimationSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+UI.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKAnnotation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+UI.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKMapView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+Styles.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKMapViewStyle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationConfiguration.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKMapsService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTDownloadManager+Additions.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTDownloadObjectHelper.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKNavigationSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPositionerService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+BackgroundMode.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+Factories.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+NavigationState.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+UI.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationUtils.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKReverseGeocoderService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationUtils.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKRouteSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+Factories.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKRoutingService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+BackgroundMode.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+NavigationState.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+Settings.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+Styles.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+UI.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKTrailSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKVisualAdviceConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+Factories.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

For now I've reverted back to the old way of doing things, but has anybody got any suggestions for getting ScoutMaps-iOS-SDKTools to play ball with use_frameworks?

Comment: We're looking into it

Comment: A fix for this issue will be delivered in the next release 3.0

Comment: and when might that be?@SylviA?